# Printing object property also prints undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object:

```
function Thing() {
    this.number = 4;
}
```

I create an instance and assign a new property:

```
var myThing = new Thing();
myThing.newProperty = 5;

console.log(myThing.newProperty);
```

and the output is:

```
5
undefined
```

Why is the output also printing undefined?

Comment: If you actually ran `console.log` from the JS console, that `undefined` is the return value from `console.log`. The console printed that after calling `log()`

Comment: If you're printing once, @PaulRoub is right. If you're printing more than once, you should include the other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to type `console.log()` into the console.  If you type in a variable, it'll print its value.

When you do `console.log(myThing.newProperty);` in the console, it runs it and shows you its return value.

`5` is shown because you *ran* `console.log`.  `undefined` is shown because that's `console.log`'s return value.